# Can I factory reset my tablet remotely?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, remote-wipe

I sold my Galaxy Tab 3 Lite on eBay. After I mailed it out to the buyer, I remember that I'd forgotten to erase it first. The problem is *not* about sensitive information. The problem is (still using my Google Password) the buyer might not be able to get into and use the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.ca/android/devicemanager) to remotely wipe (or other tasks) with your android.

Just login with your google account (should be same as the account on your device). And then select the `Erase` option.

Answer (score 0):

While [Jaskaranbir's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130071/16575) should work if you've setup device manager to do that (AFAIR it requires you gave it the corresponding permissions on your device), there are other means you can use in case you have not. Order of tasks might be important here, since as soon as your device "lost contact" to its Google account, you can no longer address it remotely:

1. Login to your Google account using your web browser
2. locate [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb), and hit the *Install* button. Select your device from the popup, which pushes the app to it.

Now you should be able to access the device via the corresponding web interface of the app developer. Another app working in a similar way is [Android Lost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost). You can find additional details in our [lost-phone](/questions/tagged/lost-phone) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info).

You can still try *ADM* after having pushed one of these apps. Just make sure to not lock out (i.e. "de-authorize" it via device manager) the tablet before you've reset it; once de-authorized, you can no longer access it ;)